# create dummy variable based on values of another variable?

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I have a large dataset with multiple columns of the following structure

```
    A    B      
1.  1.   D1  
2.  1.   D2
3.  2    D2
4.  3.   D1
5.  3.   D2
```

I'm trying to create a new data frame based on unique observations in column A, with a dummy variable "Dummy" coded as 1=D1, 2=D2, 3=both, like so:

```
    A.  Dummy
1.  1.   3
2.  2.   2
3.  3.   3
```

Any idea how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(B ~ A, df, function(x) if(all(x == "D1")) 1 else if(all(x == "D2")) 2 else 3)

#   A B
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(B = paste0(B, collapse = "_")) %>% 
  mutate(Dummy = case_when(
    B == "D1" ~ 1,
    B == "D2" ~ 2,
    B == "D1_D2" |  B == "D2_D1" ~ 3,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  )) %>% 
  select(-B)
```

Result

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      A Dummy
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     2
3     3     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'A', `if` the number of distinct elements are greater than 1, return 3 or `else` use a named vector to match the `first` element of 'B'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(A) %>% 
   summarise(Dummy = if(n_distinct(B) > 1) 3L else 
       setNames(1:2, c("D1", "D2"))[first(B)])
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      A Dummy
#* <dbl> <int>
#1     1     3
#2     2     2
#3     3     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), B = c("D1", "D2", "D2", 
"D1", "D2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1.", "2.", 
"3.", "4.", "5."))
```